# Incorrect position on elements on Net Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am currently working on a resizable Windows Forms app on Visual Studio 2022 using C# and .NET 6.0, and I'm having some trouble with the location of the elements. I'm trying to set the size and position of the elements by multiplying the width and height of the Form by a percentage, like this:

```
private void Historia_clinica_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Size = new Size(Width, (int)Math.Floor(Height * 0.05));
        panel1.Left = 0;
        panel1.Top = (int)Math.Floor(Height * 0.95);
    }
```

The problem is that even though when I print the location of the panel1 it says it is in the correct position, it appears on a completely different place. It should look like this (the blue bar at the bottom)(I positioned it manually):
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPnDJ.png)

But it looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9I4P.png)

I don't know if I'm not using correctly the Left, Top and Size properties or if they use different units, I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Don't do that. Use a `TableLayoutPanel` and add columns with widths set by percentage, then dock or anchor other controls in the cells. You might benefit from [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636-Anchor-amp-Dock-For-Automatic-Resizing). I posted that in a VB.NET forum but it's all designer stuff so it's exactly the same in C#.

Comment: Wrong properties, Height and Width include the border.  Use ClientSize.Width/Height instead.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, that worked pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix the panel at the bottom you can refer to the following code：

```
private void Historia_clinica_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width, (int)(ClientSize.Height * 0.05));
    panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
}
```